# Load elements from a nested JSON array, separated by curly brackets

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a JSON column in SQL Server database, where each row consists of multiple nested objects, surrounded by curly brackets.

I wish to extract all elements to rows where column name is the variable name in the nested object.

Example of one row:

```
[
   {
      "loanBalance":14442.72,
      "balancePeriod":"2022-02-28T00:00:00+02:00",
      "guaranteeBalance":11554.18
   },
   {
      "chargeId":"21330",
      "loanBalance":13359.71,
      "balancePeriod":"2022-03-31T00:00:00+03:00",
      "guaranteeBalance":10687.77,
      "guaranteeFeeAmount":22.41,
      "guaranteeFeeDueDate":"2022-04-24T00:00:00+03:00"
   },
   {
      "chargeId":"23466",
      "loanBalance":13223.71,
      "balancePeriod":"2022-04-30T00:00:00+03:00",
      "guaranteeBalance":10578.97,
      "guaranteeFeeAmount":20.74,
      "guaranteeFeeDueDate":"2022-06-02T00:00:00+03:00"
   }
]
```

What I tried

Data for examples

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP2;

CREATE TABLE #TEMP2 (

ID INT,
JSON_COLUMN VARCHAR(MAX)

);


INSERT INTO #TEMP2 VALUES (
1, N'[{"loanBalance": 100000.0, "balancePeriod": "2022-02-28T00:00:00+02:00", "guaranteeBalance": 75000.0}, {"chargeId": "21671", "loanBalance": 100000.0, "balancePeriod": "2022-03-31T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 75000.0, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 142.08, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2022-05-09T00:00:00+03:00"}, {"chargeId": "23678", "loanBalance": 100000.0, "balancePeriod": "2022-04-30T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 75000.0, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 137.5, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2022-06-03T00:00:00+03:00"}, {"chargeId": "26077", "loanBalance": 100000.0, "balancePeriod": "2022-05-31T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 75000.0, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 142.08, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2022-08-06T00:00:00+03:00"}, {"chargeId": "26956", "loanBalance": 100000.0, "balancePeriod": "2022-06-30T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 75000.0, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 137.5, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2022-08-12T00:00:00+03:00"}, {"chargeId": "32760", "loanBalance": 100000.0, "balancePeriod": "2022-07-31T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 75000.0, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 142.08, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2022-11-20T00:00:00+02:00"}, {"chargeId": "33605", "loanBalance": 100000.0, "balancePeriod": "2022-08-31T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 75000.0, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 142.08, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2022-12-01T00:00:00+02:00"}, {"chargeId": "36010", "loanBalance": 100000.0, "balancePeriod": "2022-09-30T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 75000.0, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 137.5, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2023-01-15T00:00:00+02:00"}, {"chargeId": "37025", "loanBalance": 100000.0, "balancePeriod": "2022-10-31T00:00:00+02:00", "guaranteeBalance": 75000.0, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 142.08, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2023-02-10T00:00:00+02:00"}, {"chargeId": "37032", "loanBalance": 100000.0, "balancePeriod": "2022-11-30T00:00:00+02:00", "guaranteeBalance": 75000.0, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 137.5, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2023-02-10T00:00:00+02:00"}, {"chargeId": "37037", "loanBalance": 100000.0, "balancePeriod": "2022-12-31T00:00:00+02:00", "guaranteeBalance": 75000.0, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 142.08, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2023-02-10T00:00:00+02:00"}]'
)
;

INSERT INTO #TEMP2 VALUES (
2, N'[{"loanBalance": 14442.72, "balancePeriod": "2022-02-28T00:00:00+02:00", "guaranteeBalance": 11554.18}, {"chargeId": "21330", "loanBalance": 13359.71, "balancePeriod": "2022-03-31T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 10687.77, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 22.41, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2022-04-24T00:00:00+03:00"}, {"chargeId": "23466", "loanBalance": 13223.71, "balancePeriod": "2022-04-30T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 10578.97, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 20.74, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2022-06-02T00:00:00+03:00"}, {"chargeId": "26511", "loanBalance": 13359.71, "balancePeriod": "2022-05-31T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 10687.77, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 21.43, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2022-08-11T00:00:00+03:00"}, {"chargeId": "31054", "loanBalance": 13359.71, "balancePeriod": "2022-06-30T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 10687.77, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 20.84, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2022-10-17T00:00:00+03:00"}, {"chargeId": "31068", "loanBalance": 13359.71, "balancePeriod": "2022-07-31T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 10687.77, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 21.54, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2022-10-17T00:00:00+03:00"}, {"chargeId": "31073", "loanBalance": 13359.71, "balancePeriod": "2022-08-31T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 10687.77, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 21.54, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2022-10-17T00:00:00+03:00"}, {"chargeId": "31075", "loanBalance": 13359.71, "balancePeriod": "2022-09-30T00:00:00+03:00", "guaranteeBalance": 10687.77, "guaranteeFeeAmount": 20.84, "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2022-10-17T00:00:00+03:00"}, {"chargeId": "37752", "loanBalance": "11903.33", "balancePeriod": "2022-10-31T00:00:00+02:00", "guaranteeBalance": "9522.66400000", "guaranteeFeeAmount": "23.8426", "guaranteeFeeDueDate": "2023-02-13T00:00:00+02:00"}]'
)
;
```

Example

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
    JSON_QUERY(JSON_COLUMN, '$[0]') AS elements
  FROM
    #TEMP2
)
SELECT
  elements.loanBalance,
  elements.balancePeriod,
  elements.guaranteeBalance,
  elements.chargeId,
  elements.guaranteeFeeAmount,
  elements.guaranteeFeeDueDate
FROM
  CTE
CROSS APPLY
  OPENJSON(CTE.elements) WITH (
    loanBalance NVARCHAR(255),
    balancePeriod NVARCHAR(255),
    guaranteeBalance NVARCHAR(255),
    chargeId nvarchar(100),
    guaranteeFeeAmount NVARCHAR(255),
    guaranteeFeeDueDate NVARCHAR(255)
  ) AS elements
;
```

It seems to only fetch the first element in curly brackets.

Note: Since JSON data string is surrounded by square brackets `[]`, I used `'$[0]'`

[image]

Expected Output

[image]

Comment: `select elements.*
from #TEMP2 as t
cross apply openjson(t.JSON_COLUMN) as o
CROSS APPLY
  OPENJSON(o.value) WITH (
    loanBalance NVARCHAR(255),
    balancePeriod NVARCHAR(255),
    guaranteeBalance NVARCHAR(255),
    chargeId nvarchar(100),
    guaranteeFeeAmount NVARCHAR(255),
    guaranteeFeeDueDate NVARCHAR(255)
  ) AS elements`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only getting the first JSON from each row with your query, what you need is the whole JSON_COLUMN itself:

```
SELECT ELEMENTS.loanBalance
     , ELEMENTS.balancePeriod
     , ELEMENTS.guaranteeBalance
     , ELEMENTS.chargeId
     , ELEMENTS.guaranteeFeeAmount
     , ELEMENTS.guaranteeFeeDueDate
FROM
  #TEMP2 T
CROSS APPLY
  OPENJSON(T.JSON_COLUMN) WITH (
    loanBalance NVARCHAR(255),
    balancePeriod NVARCHAR(255),
    guaranteeBalance NVARCHAR(255),
    chargeId nvarchar(100),
    guaranteeFeeAmount NVARCHAR(255),
    guaranteeFeeDueDate NVARCHAR(255)
  ) AS ELEMENTS;
```

Note: In your sample first row's data is missing } just before closing ].
And my appreciation to you for providing such a nice data sample to start with. We see it very seldom.

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/6CrO2jw2)